# Oracle SQL Develop: inserting txt file to sql table by cursor

Tags: sql, oracle11g, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just start to learn Oracle SQL develop.

I am thinking to write CURSOR to read text file line by line and insert to the SQL table.

However, I am not really sure the folder that I need to put text file.

Where should I put the text file  ?

and

I just started to learn CURSOR... can you give me simple example about cursor?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#i45288) is a way to handle results of queries whithin plsql, so basically, reading a file with a cursor doesn't really make sense...

There are some ways how to read a text file from plsql and insert it into a table. In most cases it should start with:

1. Put the file in a specific directory in the file system
2. Create a [DIRECTORY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5007.htm) db object that references that file system directory.

Now you can use [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_file.htm), or (IMHO, nicer) [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm).